# How to solve this problem of removing rows based on a condition when there are NA values

Tags: r, filter, subset

I have this data

```
     col1   col2
#1   2012   a
#2   1995   b
#3   1998   a
#4   2001   d
#5   2021   c
#6   2021   a
#7   NA     b
#8   NA     d
```

I want to remove the rows with 2021.

First there's this one:

```
df <- subset(df, col1 != 2021)
```

Problem: also removes #7 and #8

Then there's this one:

```
df <- filter(df, col1 != 2021)
```

Problem: Gives error: Error in initialize(...) : attempt to use zero-length variable name

Then there's this one:

```
df <- df[df$col1 != 2021, ]
```

Problem: creates this result:

```
     col1   col2
#1   2012   a
#2   1995   b
#3   1998   a
#4   2001   d
#NA  NA     NA
#NA  NA     NA
#NA  NA     NA
#NA  NA     NA
```

My goal is to get this:

```
     col1   col2
#1   2012   a
#2   1995   b
#3   1998   a
#4   2001   d
#5   NA     b
#6   NA     d
```

Comment: What you are trying to do? What's the expected output? See also [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
df = data.frame(col1 = c(2010:2022,NA, NA), col2 = c(NA, NA, rnorm(13)))

   col1       col2
1  2010         NA
2  2011         NA
3  2012  0.4247744
4  2013 -1.6378778
5  2014 -0.9633402
6  2015  1.0030133
7  2016  0.1063912
8  2017  2.2983095
9  2018 -1.0941622
10 2019  0.3604223
11 2020  0.9171499
12 2021  1.3803499
13 2022 -0.5693971
14   NA  1.1911385
15   NA  0.4741301
```

**EDIT**

```
# Proposed fix: 
df[-which(df$col1 == 2021),]

   col1       col2
1  2010         NA
2  2011         NA
3  2012  0.4247744
4  2013 -1.6378778
5  2014 -0.9633402
6  2015  1.0030133
7  2016  0.1063912
8  2017  2.2983095
9  2018 -1.0941622
10 2019  0.3604223
11 2020  0.9171499
13 2022 -0.5693971
14   NA  1.1911385
15   NA  0.4741301
```

Only the 2021 obs in col1 are removed, preserving NAs in all cols.

Comment: This one removes all observations (there are columns where half is NA and other columns where the other half is NA)

Comment: OK, check the edit please

Comment: I don't want to remove the NA in col1. I just want to remove the ones that have year = 2021

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to filter out a certain year but want to keep the rows where the year is missing. Try this.

```
df[is.na(df$col1) | df$col1 != 2021, ]
```

Comment: I updated my question. I'm sorry it wasn't clear, but I am trying to filter away the rows with that year. Logic is that people who filled in that they are born in 2021 are probably not filling out the questionnaire right. There is only one of those people, but my code either removes 200 rows, gives an error, or makes those 200 rows NA.

Answer (score 1):

A dplyr approach

```
df <- df %>% filter((col1 != 2021) %>% replace_na(TRUE))
```

Output

```
> df
  num col1 col2
1  #1 2012    a
2  #2 1995    b
3  #3 1998    a
4  #4 2001    d
5  #7   NA    b
6  #8   NA    d
```

Comment: Error in initialize(...) : attempt to use zero-length variable name

Comment: can you dput(df) and copy the output to your question above?

Comment: It wont fit. There are 350 variables and all of them have variable and value labels. Do you want the output just for the relevant columns?

Comment: dput(head(df)) ?

Comment: I tried to put it, but it doesn't allow that amount of characters.

Comment: what's the output of `str(df)`?